# How to send file content with post request from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have an image url, f.e. http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/13faae6d1de505622e81c366af990bad3968896c_m.jpg

I need to post it to server as multipard/form-data file with JS (from chrome extension)
How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Of course. There are a lot of stuff like "use upload" or get data from file input.

Comment: Guys, I have no inputs. I need to read file content with get request and send it as file to server.

Comment: You want to 'download' the image from given URL to client (JS) and then 'upload' it from client (JS) to server? I don't think it makes sense (or does it?). Just send an image URL to server and write a server script that downloads it.

Comment: @kdzwinel thank you very much! I was so stupid and don't get it!
Maybe problem is that I need to post it to 3rd party API and HAVE NO ACCESS to backend!